# Excess property checks typescript

Tags: typescript

Why I'm getting error under 'name' interface excess property using object literal?
In case of class there is no error, why this happening?

```
export interface Analyzer {
    run(matches: MatchData[]): string;
}

const literalObject: Analyzer = {
    run(mtatches: MatchData[]): string {
        return '';
    },
    name: 'asd', //error
}

export class WinsAnalysis implements Analyzer {
    name: string = 'asd'; //fine

    constructor(public team: string) {

    }

    run(matches: MatchData[]): string {
        let wins = 0;

        for (let match of matches) {
            if (match[1] === this.team && match[5] === MatchResult.HomeWin) {
                wins++;
            } else if (match[2] === this.team && match[5] === MatchResult.AwayWin) {
                wins++;
            }
        }

        return `${this.team} won ${wins} times`;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which one do you expect to be different? The literal throw an error because it's probably a mistake to throw away type information by creating an object and then immediately assigning it a narrower type. The class doesn't throw an error because "implements analyzer" doesn't mean "**only** implements analyzer". You promise that the class will have all the properties in analyzer, but you can have more.

Comment: Is this two separate questions?

Answer (score 0):

The error I got for your code was as follows:

> Type '{ run(mtatches: unknown[]): string; name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Analyzer'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'name' does not exist in type 'Analyzer'.ts(2322)

When you assign an object variable to an object type (in this case, Analyzer), you are indicating that the object will possess only the specified properties.

When you create an object literal, it must conform exactly to the shape of the interface it is being assigned to. In this case, the interface 'Analyzer' does not have the 'name' property, so when you try to assign a value to 'name' on the object literal, it throws an error.

On the other hand, when you create a class that implements the 'Analyzer' interface, the class can have additional properties or methods beyond those defined in the interface. In this case, the class 'WinsAnalysis' has the 'name' property but it is not declared in the Analyzer interface. This is why it is not giving any error.

> An interface is a contract that an object must follow.

> By making a class implement an interface, you ensure that the class contains ALL the properties and methods defined inside the interface.